# Getting my program to go back to the "top" (if statement) (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, leap-year

I have a program to calculate leap year, however, it only works past about the year 1750 so I want my user to only be able to input numbers past 1750.

```
System.out.println("Enter a year after 1750:");
    leapYear = in.nextInt();

    if(leapYear<1750){
        System.out.println("You have entered a year before 1750, please try again :");
        leapYear  = in.nextInt();
    }
```

My solution was to put a if statement. I realize, however, that this will only work if the user inputs something below 1750 once. if they do it again the program will move on. Is there a way I can execute the statement "You have entered a year before 1750, please try again :" as many times as I need to without re writing it?.

I was thinking maybe a while statement could work (if a while statement works how could I do it without causing an infinite loop)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track with a while statement. It's pretty simple to keep it from executing infinitely. As soon as the user enters a correct year, the loop condition will evaluate to false and exit.

```
System.out.println("Enter a year after 1750:");
leapYear = in.nextInt();

while(leapYear < 1750){
     System.out.println("You have entered a year before 1750, please try again :");
     leapYear  = in.nextInt();
}
```

You could also try a `do-while` loop to cut down on repeated code:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Please enter a year after 1750:");
    leapYear = in.nextInt();
}while(leapYear < 1750);
```

The user will just be reprompted to enter a year after 1750, which takes care of needing an error message.

Comment: Cheers, I assumed that the "you have entered a year before 1750" statement would execute an infinite amount of times, now I see that if you enter a year past 1750 it will just exit the loop.

Comment: You're welcome @Idan. Also check out my edit on using a `do-while` loop.

Comment: I also sometimes do something like: leapYear = 1749 and then the while loop, since I prefer the condition to be at the top-end of the brackets, rather than the bottom.

Comment: @Perry I agree with you there, I always feel funny writing a do-while, especially ones that may be a bit lengthy. I usually _do_ what you suggested or include a comment next to my `do{` to pull up the condition... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
while(leapYear<1750)
```

instead of:

```
if(leapYear<1750)
```